# How to animate by changing the background image and chnage the position of an UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

I am interested in obtaining an animation that not only animates from point A to point B but also changes the background image. 
Say the initial position is 0,0  and the finis one is 0,100 ; the duration is 1 second, and i have 4 images for the background, then i want the background to change every 0/4 seconds and 25 px.

Until now I have the next code that animates the images but i still need to implement the movement and I don't know how to do just that.

Thanks in advance and here is what code I have until now:

```
        UIImageView * animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,50)];

       testArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_3.png"],nil];
       animTime =3.0;
       [animatedImageView setAnimationImages:testArray] ;
       animatedImageView.animationDuration =  animTime;
       animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
       [self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
       [animatedImageView startAnimating];
```

**UPDATE:**

I have implemented the answer of [Mobile Project Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3993103/mobile-project-lab)  into my code

```
// I have a pathArray that is in C style and is bidimensional, that stores the path in reverse
// the maps is a 2d tile map
// the dimensions of the tiles are 64x64 px
//thes size of the character is 128x128
          for (int possitionInThePathArray = sizeOfPathArray - 1; possitionInThePathArray >= 0; possitionInThePathArray--) {

    xWalkingDirection = pathArray[possitionInThePathArray-1][1] - pathArray[possitionInThePathArray][1];  
    yWalkingDirection = pathArray[possitionInThePathArray-1][0] - pathArray[possitionInThePathArray][0];




              if (xWalkingDirection== 0 && yWalkingDirection == -1){
    //walking animation to North for 1 tile

        NSArray *testArray;
        float animTime;

        testArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s0.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s1.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s2.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s3.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s4.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s5.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s6.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s7.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s8.png"],
                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s9.png"], nil]; // 4th image added
        animTime = 10.0; // time is changed to 10.0
        [myCharacterFrame setAnimationImages:testArray];
        myCharacterFrame.animationDuration = animTime;
        myCharacterFrame.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        [myCharacterFrame startAnimating];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:animTime
                         animations:^{
                             myCharacterFrame.frame = CGRectOffset(myCharacterFrame.frame, 0.0f, -64.0f); // move 100 on x axis, 0 on y axis
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             NSLog(@"animation done");
                         }];

        yMyCharacterFrame = yMyCharacterFrame-64.0;
        myCharacterFrame.frame = CGRectMake(xMyCharacterFrame, yMyCharacterFrame, 128, 128);
        myCharacterFrame.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scientist_s0.png"];


    }else if (xWalkingDirection== 1 && yWalkingDirection == 0){
     //walking animation to Est for 1 tile
    .....
    //and so on for all the four directions of walking
```

The issue that I am facing now is that the animation are not triggered correctly, so that one animation takes places before the code moves on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *testArray;
float animTime;

UIImageView *animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
testArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_001.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_002.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_001.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_002.png"], nil]; // 4th image added
animTime = 1.0; // time is changed to 1.0
[animatedImageView setAnimationImages:testArray];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = animTime;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];


[UIView animateWithDuration:animTime
                 animations:^{
                     animatedImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(animatedImageView.frame, 100.0f, 0.0f); // move 100 on x axis, 0 on y axis
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"animation done");
                 }];
```

Comment: I just test it and seems to work just fine now comes the understanding part :D
Thank you for you help!

Comment: And how can I add a completion handle so that I make shore the animation is completed before any other line of code is executed?
Thank you in advance for the patience

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve / what other code do, you can call some other method in completion block (where NSLog(@"animation done"); is)

Comment: I am doing some sort of a mmorpg game. And I have an array that sores the path. And for each element of the array I must animate my character to go N/S/E/W. So, I run a for loop over the array and an if - else if.. and if it goes N than I call the North animation and I update the frame when it is done and so on for all the objects of the path array

Comment: This is part of a school project that I am trying to finish

Comment: don't use for loop, create global counter arrayPosition, put this code in some method moveCharacter, set arrayPosition to 0 and run method [self moveCharacter], in method add check where character should move and do animation, in completion block increase arrayPosition and if arrayPosition is < [array count] call [self moveCharacter] again, that way code will be execution until there are items in array. I hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant Idea! I will edit my code and return with a post :)